# How do I combine separate shapes for contiguous gradient fill in illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, gradient, fill

I wanted the rainbow gradient to extend to the "'s".. and not filled as separate shape. I've tried everyone of the pathfinder options and refilled.. but the same results (or just plain did not work) [image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I apply a gradient across multiple objects in Illustrator?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/45334/how-do-i-apply-a-gradient-across-multiple-objects-in-illustrator)

Comment: Yes, here's another method as well https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/107226/63979

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select all, goto Object > Compound Path > Make, recolor the shape; It's now like one.

[image]

The upper AbC is an outlined text. The lower is after making a compound path and recoloring.

CAUTION: Compound path is the way to make holes. If you release the compound path, you will create a mess. The holes you already had, get filled:

[image]

You can remake the holes by ungrouping at first and then selecting the parts of one letter at a time and making a compound path.

Comment: Oh DUH. What didn't I think of that? TYTY :)