# How to apply gradient tool to geometric shapes drawn with pen tool

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I've drawn a geometric lion that I would like to apply a gold gradient to so that it fades from front to back, like the gazelle below.

However, whenever I use the gradient color on the lion, drawn using the pen tool, the below gradient happens.

I would assume it's because of how I drew the lion with the pen, but I have no idea how to fix it.

[image: gazelle - gradient]

[image: lion - sad gradient]

Comment: This answer will help you https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/107226/63979

Comment: Is your lion stroked paths, or filled shapes?

Comment: @Scott stroked paths!

Comment: @WELZ this worked perfectly, thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

In order to get a gradient to span across a collection of objects, the object *must* be **filled paths**. Gradients on *strokes* only have 3 options and they won't *ever* "span" strokes.

So..

Do this on a **copy** of the artwork if you wish to retain teh strokes for easier editing later.

- Set the stroke to a flat color (Black)
- Select all
- choose `Object > Expand`
- Then apply a gradient **fill**
- Then use the **Gradient Tool** to click-drag across the shapes in order to make the gradient fill span the objects.

You can also group the strokes and then use the **Appearance Panel** to add a new **fill** to the group of strokes, set that fill as a gradient, and then use teh Gradient tool to span the fill across teh group.

Answer (score 2):

Since Illustrator CC it's not necessary to expand, with this you keep the original paths.

Just apply the gradient to the strokes:

[image: Gradient]

To apply the gradient to all the strokes as a unity, press <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>8</kbd> Mac or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>8</kbd> Win to create a **Compound Shape**

[image: Compound Shape]